# NestedScrollView: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We are facing a quiet strange behavior in our Xamarin forms app. Sometimes the app crashes on a Zebra Technologies MC33 device with android version 8.1.0. Xamarin forms version is 5.0.0.2478. The following exception is retrieved from the app center. I don't know how this happens and i was not able to reproduce it.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: replace (-1 ... 0) starts before 0
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1314)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:510)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:229)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:227)
  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:370)
  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:71)
  at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:479)
  at android.text.method.MpaMultiTapKeyListener.onKeyDown(MpaMultiTapKeyListener.java:261)
  at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:196)
  at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7335)
  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7112)
  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2874)
  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11713)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(NestedScrollView.java:622)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(NestedScrollView.java:622)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:440)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
  at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:130)
  at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
  at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:140)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:599)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3068)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:354)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4674)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4206)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4352)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4409)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4206)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4233)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4206)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4385)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4546)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-2)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: what actual programming language is this about?

Comment: C# with xamarin forms.

Comment: Did this issue just appear on this kind of device and worked well on others? In addition, can you debug it on this device to find which line caused this error?

Comment: The app is only used on this devices. I am not able to debug it sorry, but regarding the callstack i would say it's caused by the backspace on the hardware keyboard. Really confused why the key events are handled by the NestedScrollView and not from an entry or so.

Comment: But you said sometimes? Do you mean it works well some times?

Comment: Yes the crash appears rarely

Comment: Do all the devices running the project have the same android version?

Comment: Yes, all devices use 8.1.0.

Comment: According to the information you provided, I can't reproduce it. And the logs show the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, can you find it's location?

Comment: Really bad for me. I posted all information which i got for this issue sorry.

Comment: But according to these messages, I can't find what caused the error.